# Binary search trees with n as the root

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree

In my book, I read the following statement:

> Suppose that the tree is a binary search tree, then:
>
> If the tree contains all values from 1 to n exactly once, and n is the
>   root of the tree, then the height of the tree cannot be log2(n)
>   (rounded up)

Why does this statement hold?

Comment: Question for https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is the root, that means that all of the remaining `(n-1)` elements are on one side of the tree. Thus, the height of the tree is at least `d = 1 + log2(n-1)`

Little algebra:

```
log2(n-1) + 1 = log2(n-1) + log2(2) = log2(2(n-1)) > log2(n) for n > 2
```

So the tree that has `n` at the root cannot attain height `log2(n)` if it has more than `2` elements.

Regarding the `rouned up` part:

Let `n=17`, `17` in the root. Remaining `16` elements comprise a perfect binary tree of height `4`, so total tree depth is `5`, which contradicts the claim that the depth can't be `ceil(log2(17)) == 5`.

Comment: The height of the tree on the left side is 1+log2(n-1) in the best case right? Since in the worst case we have that all the values are to the left of each other, where height=nodes in that case.